# SQLiteException: no such table exists

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create a SQLite database within my android app, but my code consistently throws a "SQLiteException" saying that no such table exists. I am new to SQL, but I assume this means my create script isn't running properly. Part of my code is below. Please point out any errors you see and thanks in advance!

Adapter:

```
public class DBAdapter
{
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_FAVORITE = "favorite";
public static final String KEY_LAT = "lat";
public static final String KEY_LONG = "long";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "eateries";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "names";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "( "
        + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
        + KEY_FAVORITE + " integer, "
        + KEY_LAT + " text not null, "
        + KEY_LONG + " text not null, "
        + KEY_ADDRESS + " text not null, "
        + KEY_PHONE + " text not null);";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS names");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
//---closes the database---
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}
//---insert a title into the database---
public long insertNew(String name, Integer favorite, GeoPoint coords, String address, String phone)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_FAVORITE, favorite);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, coords.getLatitudeE6());
    initialValues.put(KEY_LONG, coords.getLongitudeE6());
    initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);

    return db.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Calling code:
    package bhekman.test.database;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DBAdapter dba = new DBAdapter(this);
        dba.open();
        dba.insertNew("mc. awesome", 1, new GeoPoint(0, 0), "42 SUPER AWESOME DRIVE", "(616)-994-2421");

        Toast.makeText(this, dba.getName(0).getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dba.close();
    }
}
```

LogCat Error:

```
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bhekman.test.database/bhekman.test.database.DatabaseActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: names: , while compiling: INSERT INTO names(phone, long, favorite, address, lat, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: names: , while compiling: INSERT INTO names(phone, long, favorite, address, lat, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1569)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1452)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at bhekman.test.database.DBAdapter.insertNew(DBAdapter.java:93)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at bhekman.test.database.DatabaseActivity.onCreate(DatabaseActivity.java:18)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-05 22:06:29.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4785):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: just throw a sqlite error on query failure and read the error. You will have to do this all day long forever and ever so you might as well get started now.

Comment: post insertNew method please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine in my computer with your code. 
so I guess that you change the TABLE name during your development. and just run the program again with eclipse's RUN command. So the application was not a fresh install. but you don't implement the onUpgrade() correctly.

to solve your problem you met quickly.

1. uninstall the program with adb uninstall
2. reinstall the program.

Comment: I tried it— no dice.
List of datatypes here: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqldatatypes.php

Comment: Oh, my bad. Good point.
Still, the code gives the same error if I replace "bit" with "integer".

Comment: Can you post more codes. In particularly the method execute the insert operation.

Comment: Orz. Post insertView method please.

Comment: I edit my answer. and I test the code in my computer. It works fine.

Comment: I tried the uninstall, and it got me past the no such table exception- THANK YOU.
The query is giving me a new problem now (CursorIndexOutOfBounds), but the code runs if I comment it out.

Comment: Thanks, I just added it. I tried adding 3 things to database and querying them all, but got a size of zero. I probably need to fix the query parameters.

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood the selection parameter. It works. Thanks again for your fantastic help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you made changes to the table after you initially created it (meaning run it on your phone/emulator)? Like maybe adding a new table, or changing the name of it?

If so, you need to change your `DATABASE_VERSION` to 2 so that the database will be upgraded to your latest schema.

And  `KEY_FAVORITE + " bit, "` needs to be  `KEY_FAVORITE + " integer, "`.  And if you make that change, you need to update your DATABASE_VERSION too.

Basically for **anything** that makes a change to the structure of the database you need to increase the version so the database will re-create the database with your new changes.

Comment: The only changes made are the ones shown in the calling code that I added above. I don't think they necessitate changing the version, but tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Honestly, it's quick and I'd try changing the version number anyway and see what happens, because I can't see anything wrong, although seeing your insertNew method might help in diagnosis.  Oh, just noticed, you are using true and bit... try integer and 1 instead (with a version update).

Comment: I did override the onUpdate method, I just didn't post it. I'll add it.
Does that code manage the versioning, or is the versioning managed manually (Do I have to increase the version myself, if so how?)?

Comment: I switched to integer based on Changwei's answer. Doesn't onUpdate manage the versioning for me?

Comment: onUpdate takes care of it (if you've set it up to) after you tell it there's a new version by changing `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;` (or whatever the relevant next revision number would be).

Comment: Although that didn't solve it directly, you were on the right track. A simple uninstall fixed the problem because it removed the database and recreated it. Thanks!!