# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: No such table exists

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sample Android app in which I created a database, created a table and then inserted data into the table. The next day, on opening the Eclipse IDE and running my app through the emulator, the app suddenly gets closed, with a SQLLiteException saying `No such table`.

My MainActivity code is as follows:

```
SQLiteDatabase DB = Context.openOrCreateDatabase(
        "WaterElectricityReadingDataBase.db",
        MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);

final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table if not exists "
        + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_READING_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
        + COLUMN_NAME_READING_MODE + " text not null,"
        + COLUMN_NAME_PASTDATETIME + " date not null, "
        + "EndDateTime date not null, "
        + COLUMN_NAME_READINGVALUE + " integer not null" + ");";

DB.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

Is the table or data not persistent? Have I missed anything in the setup?

Please correct me, thanks.

Comment: Post the logcat output

Comment: pls refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568861/sqliteexception-no-such-table-exists

Comment: Can you try to run on a phone?

Comment: The previous day could you successfully read the data from the table?

Comment: yes. I was able to read the data. For the next day everything has become fresh. Table was deleted and the data in it too

Comment: I think you should remove the semicilon from the end of the query after the `)` bracket and then try to run it. Besides this `COLUMN_NAME_READINGVALUE + " integer not null" + ");";` try with this `COLUMN_NAME_READINGVALUE + " integer not null" + ")";`. See the change at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like :

```
final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table if not exists "
            + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_READING_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_READING_MODE + " text not null,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_PASTDATETIME + " date not null, "
            + "EndDateTime date not null, "
            + COLUMN_NAME_READINGVALUE + " integer not null);";
```

and tell me working or not?

Good Luck.